# Webscraping html tables with variable length - How do I make sure my data ends up in the correct columns when constructing a dataframe?

Tags: r, html-parsing, data-cleaning, rvest

I (beginner to intermediate R user) am trying to webscrape data about a large amount (~12k) of buildings in Berlin.

The information can be found on the webpages (**one for each building**, so 12k) of Berlin's heritage agency, that all look like [this](https://www.stadtentwicklung.berlin.de/denkmal/liste_karte_datenbank/de/denkmaldatenbank/daobj.php?obj_dok_nr=09097874) (website is in German, the data I'm interested in is the table in the center that starts with **Obj.-Dok-Nr**.: 09XXXXXXX and the following lines, containing suburb, address etc.).

All the urls end with `obj_dok_nr=09xxxxxx (09097890-09010001)` which corresponds to the internal ID of the buildings, each field of the table has the following css selector:

```
.denkmal_detail_head+ .denkmal_detail_body tr:nth-child(n) td+ td
```

with n being an integer from counting up from 1.

I already have all the 09XXXXXXX IDs in a seperate dataframe called **denkmal_df** that I've build from a json file I found elsewhere.

I wrote this code to retrieve the data:

```r
get_URL <- function(key) { #assemble an URL from a denkmal key
  url <- paste0("https://www.stadtentwicklung.berlin.de/denkmal/liste_karte_datenbank/de/denkmaldatenbank/daobj.php?obj_dok_nr=", key)
  return(url)
}

get_Data <- function(url, i, static_css_1, static_css_2) { #Webscraper core, needs to be more flexible, but gets the job done
  css_key <- paste0(static_css_1,i,static_css_2)#Assemble css key to extract information
  print(css_key)
  data <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(css = css_key ) %>% html_text() #extract information
  return(data)
}

web_data <- matrix(as.character(NA), nrow = 13, ncol = 13) %>% data.frame() #%>% as_tibble() # prepare Dataframe, faster than creating it in the loop # Why can't I create the tibble directly? matrix(NA, nrow = length(denkmal_df$key), ncol = 13) %>% tibble results in a tibble with one column
temp_data <- NA
css1 <- ".denkmal_detail_head tr:nth-child(" #define css structure # possible improvement: more flexibility
css2 <- ") td+ td"

for(key in 1:length(denkmal_df$keys)){ #loop over all the denkmal keys, using an index called key
      i <- 1
      temp_data <- NA
      url <- get_URL(denkmal_df$keys[key]) #retrieve the url by passing the actual denkmal key to the get_URL function
      print(url)
      while (is_empty(temp_data) == F){ #start scraping the website belonging to the current denkmal, until no information can be found (temp_data = empty)
        temp_data <- get_Data(url, i, css1, css2) #retrieve the first category of data, which is indexed on the website by a css path + a number (1 for the first item, 2 for the second...) -> i
        if (i >= ncol(web_data) & is_empty(temp_data) == F) { #check if all columns in the data frame are full, but we still got data from a new category
          web_data[key, i+1:i+5] <- as.character(NA) #expand dataframe with a bunch of NA columns
        }

        if (is_empty(temp_data) == T) {#writing empty values into a dataframe throws an error, so we convert to NA
          temp_data <- as.character(NA)
          web_data[key, i] <- temp_data
          temp_data <- character(0) # and back to empty, to exit the while loop
        }
        else {
          web_data[key, i] <- temp_data # write data to the data frame in row = key(corresponds to postion of the actual key), column = i (represents the category)
          i <- i+1 # increase i to extract the second/etc category, rinse and repeat until no categories are left (temp_data = empty)
        }

      }
    }
```

While it scrapes the data fine, the resulting dataframe is a mess. Since **some html tables have more entries than others** (compare [this](https://www.stadtentwicklung.berlin.de/denkmal/liste_karte_datenbank/de/denkmaldatenbank/daobj.php?obj_dok_nr=09097882) and [this](https://www.stadtentwicklung.berlin.de/denkmal/liste_karte_datenbank/de/denkmaldatenbank/daobj.php?obj_dok_nr=09097886), multiple addresses is common) the values are all over the place:
(Note that some have been cut ~ by the tibble formatting)

```
> as_tibble(web_data)
# A tibble: 13 x 13
   X1      X2          X3      X4       X5                                           X6           X7           X8          X9      X10          X11        X12    X13  
   <chr>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>    <chr>                                        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       <chr>   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>  <chr>
 1 090978~ Mitte       Gesund~ Putbuss~ 12                                           Swinemünder~ Gesamtanlage Schule & B~ NA      NA           NA         NA     NA   
 2 090978~ Charlotten~ Westend Messeda~ 11 & 12                                      Hammarskjöl~ Baudenkmal   Kongressge~ NA      NA           NA         NA     NA   
 3 090978~ Mitte       Tierga~ Rauchst~ 4 & 5 & 6                                    Stülerstraße 2 & 4        Thomas-Deh~ 1 & 3 ~ Gartendenkm~ Siedlungs~ NA     NA   
 4 090978~ Reinickend~ Tegel   Am Tege~ 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 8A & 8B & 8C & 8D & 8E & 10~ Gartendenkm~ Siedlungsgr~ NA          NA      NA           NA         NA     NA   
 5 090978~ Charlotten~ Wilmer~ Prager ~ 4 & 5                                        Prager Stra~ 13           Prinzregen~ 97      Asschaffenb~ Gesamtanl~ Stadt~ NA   
 6 090978~ Mitte       Tierga~ Reichpi~ 48 & 50                                      Gesamtanlage Forschungse~ NA          NA      NA           NA         NA     NA   
 7 090978~ Mitte       Tierga~ Rauchst~ 4 & 5 & 6                                    Stülerstraße 2 & 4        Thomas-Deh~ 1 & 3 ~ Gesamtanlage Wohnanlage NA     NA   
 8 090978~ Mitte       Tierga~ Pohlstr~ 77                                           Baudenkmal   Wohn- und G~ NA          NA      NA           NA         NA     NA   
 9 090978~ Mitte       Tierga~ Lützowu~ 1A & 1B & 2 & 2A & 3 & 3A & 4 & 4A & 5 & 5A  Gesamtanlage Wohnanlage   NA          NA      NA           NA         NA     NA   
10 090978~ Mitte       Tierga~ Lützows~ 44 & 44A & 45 & 45A & 45B & 45C & 45D & 45E~ Gesamtanlage Wohnanlage ~ NA          NA      NA           NA         NA     NA
```

**I want every street name (eg. "Pohlstr(aße)", "Stülerstraße") for each builing in a column with all the other street names, all building types (eg. "Wohnanlage", "Schule") in a column etc. 
How can I achieve this?**

I already tried scraping the whole html tables into a dataframe, but that yieled similar results. I have no way of knowing the maximum mumber of entries except by running the whole loop for all 12k html sites.
(Also, if my existing code can be improved in some way, feel free to give tips

Answer (score 1):

This a page is a mess, but with some tricky CSS selectors this may answer your solve your problem.  The given page has 11 houses which need to be parsed.?

See if this is at least partially correct.

See the comments for an explanation of the code.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url<-"https://www.stadtentwicklung.berlin.de/denkmal/liste_karte_datenbank/de/denkmaldatenbank/daobj.php?obj_dok_nr=09097874"
page <- read_html(url)
#select nodes
#find the denkmal_detail_body node after the  table.denkmal_detail_sub with 1 intermedidary
infolist<- page %>% html_nodes("table.denkmal_detail_sub + * + table.denkmal_detail_body")
houses <- infolist %>% html_table()

#convert the list of nodes into data frames
dfs<-lapply(houses, function(house){
   #transform to a single row dataframe
   df<-as.data.frame(t(house$X2))
   #rename the columns
   names(df) <-house$X1
   df
})
#bind into the answer
answer <-bind_rows(dfs)


answer

        Teil-Nr.: Sachbegriff:         Strasse:                                                  Hausnummer:
1  09097874,T,001   Stadtvilla Am Tegeler Hafen                                                            2
2  09097874,T,002   Stadtvilla Am Tegeler Hafen                                                            4
3  09097874,T,003   Stadtvilla  Am Tegelerhafen                                                            6
4  09097874,T,004   Stadtvilla Am Tegeler Hafen                                                            8
5  09097874,T,005   Wohnanlage Am Tegeler Hafen                                       8A & 8B & 8C & 8D & 8E
6  09097874,T,006   Stadtvilla Am Tegeler Hafen                                                           10
7  09097874,T,007   Stadtvilla Am Tegeler Hafen                                                           12
8  09097874,T,008   Wohnanlage Am Tegeler Hafen                             14 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 22 & 24 & 26
9  09097874,T,009   Wohnanlage Am Tegeler Hafen 28 & 28A & 28B & 28C & 28D & 28E & 28F & 28G & 28H & 30 & 32
10  09097874,T,10   Wohnanlage Am Tegeler Hafen                                       34 & 36 & 38 & 40 & 42
11 09097874,T,011   Stadtvilla Am Tegeler Hafen                                                           44
                                                                                      Entwurf:
1                              Moore, Charles Willard & Ruble, John & Yudell, Buzz (Architekt)
2                                                    Steinebach, Karl-Heinz & Weber, Friedrich
3                                                      Stern, Robert Arthur Morton (Architekt)
4                                                                           Tigermann, Stanley
5              Bangert, Dietrich & Jansen, Bernd & Scholz, Stefan & Schultes, Axel (Architekt)
6                                                                Portoghesi, Paolo (Architekt)
7                                                                            Grumbach, Antoine
8  Steinebach, Karl-Heinz & Weber, Friedrich & Poly, Regina (Architekt & Landschaftsarchitekt)
9                              Moore, Charles Willard & Ruble, John & Yudell, Buzz (Architekt)
10             Bangert, Dietrich & Jansen, Bernd & Scholz, Stefan & Schultes, Axel (Architekt)
11                                                                    Hejduk, John (Architekt)
```

Comment: Nice. More robust css than my first attempt of _.denkmal_detail_body ~ div + .denkmal_detail_body_